# A-Frame: Update entity rotation from controller rotation

Tags: aframe

I am updating the y rotation of an entity from my laser controller's y rotation. The problem is that the y rotation of the controller is not added to the existing y rotation of the entity. For example: I rotate the entity by clicking on a button on my controller. The entity is rotated like my controller. But I would like to keep that rotation of the entity and ADD the rotation of my controller the next time I decide to rotate the entity.

The current behavior is implemented like that:

```
tick: function () {
  this.el.object3D.rotation.y = this.laser.object3D.rotation.y;
}
```

What I would like is

```
this.el.object3D.rotation.y = this.el.object3D.rotation.y + this.laser.object3D.rotation.y;
```

And it should work in the other direction as well

```
this.el.object3D.rotation.y = this.el.object3D.rotation.y - this.laser.object3D.rotation.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Needs more context, link to illustrate. You have to keep track of the initial rotation of the entity and then you can do:

`this.el.object3D.rotation.y = initialRotation.y + this.laser.object3D.rotation.y;`

Comment: The entity I want to rotate with the controller in VR is all around me. This example shows the issue I have, in VR: https://rough-asp.glitch.me/ The rotation is always reset. What I want is look-controls behavior (like it is in 2D using a mouse) but using a controller in VR. Thanks!

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my example? If I do the code you suggested, to keep track of the initial rotation, and if I hold the button on the controller, it spins constantly, because the initial rotation is added on each tick. I am really out of ideas how to achieve a simple spinning by controller.